# D3 circle pack - Adding labels to nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, circle-pack

While I've seen this question asked a few times, I'm having a bit trouble implementing. What I'd like to do is have the `label` attribute centered within each circle (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857615/placing-labels-at-the-center-of-nodes-in-d3-js)).  I believe I'd be adding the text attribute to:

```
canvas.selectAll('circles')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('svg:circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', function (d) {
        return d.r;
    })
    .attr('fill', function (d) {
        return d.color;
    });
```

But am confused on why the instructions they gave in the previous example I linked to doesn't work with the setup I currently have. I believe it's the `pack` option that could be throwing me off (about the difference between the two), but any further examples would be a huge help. Thanks!

### Update

Thanks for the answers/suggestions, I updated [the Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmajD) with my progress (as I needed two lines of data; should have clarified) which seems to be working well. Now this is packing into a circle - at the end of the day, I'd love for this to be packed in the actual `#canvas` width/height (which is a rectangle). I saw [this treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) example - would that be what I'm going for here?

[Demo of what I have so far](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmajD)

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. You just need to add the `text` elements -- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmgHy

Comment: +1 for attr("text-anchor", "middle")

Comment: Only you know what you want in the end -- we can't really tell you what you're going for.

Comment: A bit cryptic, but yes, I'm looking for any examples of how I can pack circles in an arbitrary shape (in this case, a rectangle -> 1000x500)

Comment: In this case, you should have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339615/packing-different-sized-circles-into-rectangle-d3-js).

Comment: That's actually the base of my code already, but as the OP mentioned, it's not actually doing anything different. So, that means a new layout would need to be created? Newer to D3, but it's hard to imagine something like this hasn't come up at least a few times to warrant a closer look at what could be done.

Comment: There's no layout that allows you to pack circles into arbitrary shapes.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the confusion is that you can't add labels to the circle selection (because in SVG, a `circle` element can't contain a `text` element). You need to either make a `g` element that contains both circle and text, or a separate selection for the text, e.g.:

```
canvas.selectAll('text')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr('y', function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    // sets the horizontal alignment to the middle
    .attr('text-anchor', "middle")
    // sets the vertical alignment to the middle of the line
    .attr('dy', '0.35em')
    .text(function(d) { 
      return d.label;
    });
```

See the updated demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/djebv