# d3 text doesn't move with the nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript

I hava tried some methods, such as [d3 Node Labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102795/d3-node-labeling) proposed by mbostock. But it doesn't work, my text still doesn't move with the nodes, they are static.

(Coded by using CoffeeScript)

```
vis = d3.select(selection).append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
linksG = vis.append("g").attr("class", "links")
nodesG = vis.append("g").attr("class", "nodes")
labelG = vis.append("g").attr("class", "labels")

nodeP = nodesG.selectAll("circle.node")
  .data(curNodesDataP)
nodeP.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .style("fill", (d) -> nodeColors(d.id))
  .style("stroke", (d) -> strokeFor(d))
  .style("stroke-width", 1.0)
  .call(force.drag)

text = labelG.selectAll("text")
  .data(curNodesDataP)
text.enter().append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text((d) -> d.id)
```

I have troubled that several days, and how can i repair it? Thanks!

--zzcheng

Comment: You're not using the approach in the question you've linked to.

Comment: I'm a novice for coffeescript and d3, however, I think the program fragment is same to that (the same circle and text operation).

Comment: No, you're not grouping the `text` and `circle` elements. I suggest having a close look at the question you've linked to and the DOM structure it generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the links, nodes and labels in separate g groups. So you should update the position of each group in tick function (Link group, Node group and label Group).

Here is a sample fiddle for the same. Note that I am updating position of label group also in the tick function.

```js
var w = 900,
    h = 400;

var circleWidth = 5;

var nodes = [{
    "name": "Matteo"
}, {
    "name": "Daniele"
}, {
    "name": "Marco"
}, {
    "name": "Lucio"
}, {
    "name": "Davide"
}];

var links = [{
    source: nodes[0],
    target: nodes[1]
}, {
    source: nodes[1],
    target: nodes[2]
}, {
    source: nodes[0],
    target: nodes[3]
}, {
    source: nodes[4],
    target: nodes[2]
}, {
    source: nodes[2],
    target: nodes[3]
}];



var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("class", "stage")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([])
    .gravity(0.1)
    .charge(-1000)
    .size([w, h]);

var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke", "#CCC")
    .attr("fill", "none");

var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

var labels = vis.selectAll("text.label")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "label");   

//CIRCLE
node.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", circleWidth)
    .attr("fill", "pink");


//TEXT
labels.append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return circleWidth + 5;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            return circleWidth + 0
        } else {
            return 8
        }
    })
    .attr("font-family", "Bree Serif")
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("font-size", "1em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d, i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            return "beginning";
        } else {
            return "end"
        }
    })



force.on("tick", function(e) {
    node.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });
  
    labels.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});

force.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Other possible and more efficient way would be to group nodes and labels together. Here is a sample fiddle in which nodes and labels are grouped and updated position of the node group and link group only in tick function.

```js
var w = 900,
    h = 400;

var circleWidth = 5;

var nodes = [{
    "name": "Matteo"
}, {
    "name": "Daniele"
}, {
    "name": "Marco"
}, {
    "name": "Lucio"
}, {
    "name": "Davide"
}];

var links = [{
    source: nodes[0],
    target: nodes[1]
}, {
    source: nodes[1],
    target: nodes[2]
}, {
    source: nodes[0],
    target: nodes[3]
}, {
    source: nodes[4],
    target: nodes[2]
}, {
    source: nodes[2],
    target: nodes[3]
}];



var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("class", "stage")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([])
    .gravity(0.1)
    .charge(-1000)
    .size([w, h]);

var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke", "#CCC")
    .attr("fill", "none");

var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

//CIRCLE
node.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", circleWidth)
    .attr("fill", "pink");
//TEXT
node.append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return circleWidth + 5;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            return circleWidth + 0
        } else {
            return 8
        }
    })
    .attr("font-family", "Bree Serif")
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("font-size", "1em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d, i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            return "beginning";
        } else {
            return "end"
        }
    })



force.on("tick", function(e) {
    node.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        })
});

force.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```