# Add labels to force layout where data is only client side (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am using the force layout example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/bsullins/4e6ea24fe0739c88a2fd95125a616a5b)

I need to add labels to the nodes. All examples I have seen use something like this:

```
node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

But this works when there is a function being called on local data such as:

```
d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
```

But in my example the data is all client side and thus does not require d3.json to pass over it. How can I add labels to each node in this scenario? Below is the code I am using:

```
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set a width and height for our SVG
var width = 1000,
height = 800;

// setup links
var links = [
{ source: 'Baratheon', target:'Lannister' },
{ source: 'Baratheon', target:'Stark' },
{ source: 'Lannister', target:'Stark' },
{ source: 'Stark', target:'Bolton' },
];

// create empty nodes array
var nodes = {};

// compute nodes from links data
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});


// add a SVG to the body for our viz
var svg=d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

// use the force
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .linkDistance(300)
    .start();

// add links
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');

// add nodes
var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', width * 0.01);


// what to do
function tick(e) {

    node.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(force.drag);

    link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example of labeling you cited works because each node is bound to an object by the `.data()` method. Each one of these objects has a `name` property that contains the label for the node.

In your code, you already have this set up! Your nodes are bound to the `force.nodes()` array of objects, whose children all have `name` properties. All you have to do is call `node.text(function(d) { return d.name })`.

By default, these labels will not be visible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102795/d3-node-labeling) for ideas on how to display node labels.